# Fine Grained Access Control over endpoints of my REST application endpoints using OKTA and OAUTH

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, okta

### Overview

---

I have a REST application which has say 1 endpoint /ebook

It has 3 HTTP verbs associated with it get (For fetching ebook details), post (For adding ebook), delete (For deleting ebook)

Fetching ebook is available for all users in the system.
Creating and deleting ebook will require admin access.

I want the users having admin access only to add or delete an ebook, to put it in another way users having read access only SHOULD NOT be able to add or delete ebooks.

***I am not able to set up this level of fine-grained access. With my setup even users with read access only are able to add, delete ebook.***

---

### OKTA Configuration

I have configured the ebook application and configured OKTA as the Authorization server. I am able to obtain access token to access the application

Fetching ebook is available for all users and I have created scope ebook:read for that purpose in the OKTA authorization server.
Creating and deleting ebook will require admin access and I have created scope ebook:modify for this

I have created two user Applications in OKTA.

1. ReaderApp - This application can only be used to Read ebooks.
2. AdminApp - This application can be used to Read, Add and Delete ebooks

I have assigned the required users/groups to these applications.

Next, I created 2 Access Policies in the Authorization Server

1. Read Access Policy - For this policy I have assigned ReaderApp as a client and created a Rule to accept "Any user assigned the app" and scope requested is "ebook:read"
2. Admin Access Policy - For this policy I have assigned AdminApp as a client and created a Rule to accept "Any user assigned the app" and scope requested is "ebook:read", "ebook:modify"

In the Authorization Server i have only added Scope and access policy , i haven't touched other stuffs like Claim etc.

---

### Issue

The following is working for me as expected until now:

1. Both AdminApp and ReaderApp is not able to access ebooks without an access token
2. ReaderApp is successful to access ebook from EbookApp by requesting **ebook:read** scope.
3. ReaderApp is failing to create/delete ebook in EbookApp by requesting **ebook:modify** scope.
4. AdminApp is successful to read/create/delete ebook in EbookApp by requesting **ebook:modify** scope.

---

However, the below is **NOT** working as expected:

1. ReaderApp is able to read/create/delete ebook in 
   by requesting **ebook:read** scope. **This should not happen**

---

Is it possible to prevent ReaderApp to be able create/delete ebook by requesting "ebook:read" scope.

Both the Applications AdminApp and ReaderApp use the same endpoint /ebook.

For ReaderApp the **post** and **delete** methods should not be accessible in this endpoint, Even though i have protected them using scopes but it is not associated directly to the endpoints which is the problem

I think I may have missed something very basic, but since I am new to OKTA I am not able to figure it out yet.

Is this something that I have to configure in the Ebook Application (Resource Server) itself or is it possible to handle this situation using OKTA only maybe with some Authorization Server configurations.
Any suggestions are welcome.

**Note:** In this post i have mentioned only 1 endpoint with few http verbs for the sake of clarity but in my actual application there are a lot of endpoints